# Google Drive List All Folders and Files

Tags: api, sdk, google-drive-api, drive

Hi I'm looking for a way to get a list for all my folders, sub folders and files from my google drive. I would like it to create a spreadsheet in my drive that outputs:

-All folders names, all sub folder names, all files names and there id (if not the id the url or both). Optional if it is possible output the description

Ive tried the code display on this post that works but it only gives me the file name and link in the parent folder only but I would like all mention information.

if someone knows the correct full code?

```
 // replace your-folder below with the folder for which you want a listing
 function listFolderContents() {
   var foldername = 'your-folder';
   var folderlisting = 'listing of folder ' + foldername;

   var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername)
   var folder = folders.next();
   var contents = folder.getFiles();

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);
   var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
   sheet.appendRow( ['name', 'link'] );

   var file;
   var name;
   var link;
   var row;
   while(contents.hasNext()) {
     file = contents.next();
     name = file.getName();
     link = file.getUrl();
     sheet.appendRow( [name, link] );     
   }  
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Execute this URI request which I generated from the [Drive API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.list?fields=files%252CincompleteSearch%252Ckind%252CnextPageToken&_h=1&):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=files%2CincompleteSearch%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken
```

It will return all your files and the its metada - complete info, which is found in [File Resource properties](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource).